# Place a Window behind desktop icons using PyQt on Ubuntu/GNOME

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5, gnome, xlib

I'm trying to develop a simple cross-platform Wallpaper manager, but I am not able to find any method to place my PyQt Window between the current wallpaper and the desktop icons using XLib (on windows and macOS it's way easier and works perfectly).

This works right on Cinnamon (with a little workround just simulating a click), but not on GNOME. Can anyone help or give me any clue? (I'm providing all this code just to provide a minimum executable piece, but the key part, I guess, is right after 'if "GNOME"...' sentence)

```
import os
import time

import Xlib
import ewmh
import pywinctl
from pynput import mouse

DISP = Xlib.display.Display()
SCREEN = DISP.screen()
ROOT = DISP.screen().root
EWMH = ewmh.EWMH(_display=DISP, root=ROOT)


def sendBehind(hWnd):

        w = DISP.create_resource_object('window', hWnd)
        w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM, 32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE_BELOW', False), ], Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
        w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM, 32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR', False), ], Xlib.X.PropModeAppend)
        w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM, 32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER', False), ], Xlib.X.PropModeAppend)
        DISP.flush()

        # This sends window below all others, but not behind the desktop icons
        w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM, 32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP', False), ],Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
        DISP.flush()

        if "GNOME" in os.environ.get('XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP', ""):
            # This sends the window "too far behind" (below all others, including Wallpaper, like unmapped)
            # Trying to figure out how to raise it on top of wallpaper but behind desktop icons
            desktop = _xlibGetAllWindows(title="gnome-shell")
            if desktop:
                w.reparent(desktop[-1], 0, 0)
                DISP.flush()
        else:
            # Mint/Cinnamon: just clicking on the desktop, it raises, sending the window/wallpaper to the bottom!
            m = mouse.Controller()
            m.move(SCREEN.width_in_pixels - 1, 100)
            m.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)

        return '_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP' in EWMH.getWmWindowType(hWnd, str=True)


def bringBack(hWnd, parent):
    w = DISP.create_resource_object('window', hWnd)

    if parent:
        w.reparent(parent, 0, 0)
        DISP.flush()

    w.unmap()
    w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM,
                      32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL', False), ],
                      Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
    DISP.flush()
    w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM,
                      32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED', False), ],
                      Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
    DISP.flush()
    w.map()
    EWMH.setActiveWindow(hWnd)
    EWMH.display.flush()
    return '_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL' in EWMH.getWmWindowType(hWnd, str=True)


def _xlibGetAllWindows(parent: int = None, title: str = ""):

    if not parent:
        parent = ROOT
    allWindows = [parent]

    def findit(hwnd):
        query = hwnd.query_tree()
        for child in query.children:
            allWindows.append(child)
            findit(child)

    findit(parent)
    if not title:
        matches = allWindows
    else:
        matches = []
        for w in allWindows:
            if w.get_wm_name() == title:
                matches.append(w)
    return matches


hWnd = pywinctl.getActiveWindow()
parent = hWnd._hWnd.query_tree().parent
sendBehind(hWnd._hWnd)
time.sleep(3)
bringBack(hWnd._hWnd, parent)
```

Comment: So you're saying you can place a window between the wallpaper and the desktop icons in windows?

Comment: Exactly. On windows, macOs and cinnamon, but not in GNOME. Check this if you are interested: https://github.com/Kalmat/PyWinCtl

Comment: On my Ubuntu, this immediately closes whichever window I have in focus; you might have warned us :-). Also, you forgot to `import os`.

Comment: @Kalma That is so cool! Thanks for the link :)

Comment: So, just for clarification, you want your window to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlYHb.jpg), where it's behind the icons on the Desktop, but in front of the wallpaper? (that image is edited to demonstrate; unfortunately I didn't get your code to work).

Comment: Exactly! That's the idea! Sorry for the inconveniences @SylvesterKruin. The window doesn't close... as you can read on the comment, it sends the window "too far behind" (below all others including wallaper)!!!!! How did you manage to get GTKEditor as expected?

Comment: You're welcome! @AnnZen. It's the project I'm working in, and this that I'm asking is one of the few things which remains pending (as well as a lot of testing on "real" applications and developments)

Comment: @SylvesterKruin, sorry I didn't properly understood your message... now I realize it's an edited image. I think my code works, but not as expected. Perhaps the strategy of reparenting it is not the way to go (on Cinnamon is enough changing properties and then clicking... no reparenting at all), or maybe reparenting it to something else...

Comment: @Kalma Sorry for the false positive :-)! Also, I realized that yes, your tactic does actually keep the windows open, just below the wallpaper. When I hit `Super` (the little Windows-looking key), I can see the affected window briefly. I'll see if I can find a solution, and I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Did you get to interact with the trapped window?

Comment: @AnnZen I don't think so. It was there too briefly to do anything with it. I have to `kill` it in the terminal to get it to go away.

Comment: Another odd thing: I'm on Ubuntu, which uses GNOME, but the GNOME code in your question doesn't run; the Cinnamon code runs! If I try to run the GNOME code unconditionally, I get a `Xlib.error.BadWindow` error message. When I call `print(os.environ.get('XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP', ""))`, it prints `Unity`. This is rather confusing. At this point, we might ask _why_ you want to put the window behind the desktop icons; do you want the window to _be_ the wallpaper, or do you want the window to be a _preview_ for the wallpaper?

Comment: Hi! Unity was the Ubuntu environment until 2017, when canonical went back to GNOME. I didn't test this on Unity yet because I wanted to focus on mainstream versions first (Linux variety of WMs is a nightmare!). Anyway, I will dig into it as well. BadWindow error happens because I'm using "gnome-shell" to reparent the window. Thus, "gnome-shell" is not present in Unity. And yes, I am developing a wallpaper manager which allows to show images, carousel of images, local video, YouTube Video, ... Check this if you are curious: https://github.com/Kalmat/jaaw

Comment: Thank you both for your interest! As soon as I can, I will edit my original question to add a "bring back to life" function. In your case (in which reparenting fails), this should be enough to bring it back: '''w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM, 32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL', False), ],Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)'''. Anyway, I will add that function as soon as I get home again.

Comment: I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242600/window-as-wallpaper-in-gnome) for this question, if you or @AnnZen are interested in continuing discussion there. I think there are a little too many comments on this question for easy reading :-)!

Comment: @Kalma Left a response in that chat room :)

Comment: @Kalma Sigh... didn't mean to ignore your message, I didn't know you replied in that chat room. If only this feature was implemented :') [Follow chat room feature (for everyone or just ROs, depending on which is better)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375470/773001)

Comment: HAHAHAHA! Don't worry at all!!! Yes, that feature would be really helpful. I'm still struggling with the issue. In parallel, I'm working on a new multi-display version... which is also challenging! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka!!! Last Ubuntu version (22.04) seems to have brought the solution by itself. It now has a "layer" for desktop icons you can interact with. This also gave me the clue to find a smarter solution on Mint/Cinnamon (testing in other OS is still pending). This is the code which seems to work OK, for those with the same issue:

```
import time

import Xlib.display
import ewmh
import pywinctl

DISP = Xlib.display.Display()
SCREEN = DISP.screen()
ROOT = DISP.screen().root
EWMH = ewmh.EWMH(_display=DISP, root=ROOT)


def sendBehind(hWnd):
    w = DISP.create_resource_object('window', hWnd.id)
    w.unmap()
    w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM,
                      32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP', False), ],
                      Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
    DISP.flush()
    w.map()

    # This will try to raise the desktop icons layer on top of the window
    # Ubuntu: "@!0,0;BDHF" is the new desktop icons NG extension
    # Mint: "Desktop" name is language-dependent. Using its class (nemo-desktop)
    desktop = _xlibGetAllWindows(title="@!0,0;BDHF", klass=('nemo-desktop', 'Nemo-desktop'))
    for d in desktop:
        w = DISP.create_resource_object('window', d)
        w.raise_window()

    return '_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP' in EWMH.getWmWindowType(hWnd, str=True)


def bringBack(hWnd):

    w = DISP.create_resource_object('window', hWnd.id)

    w.unmap()
    w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM,
                      32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL', False), ],
                      Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
    DISP.flush()
    w.change_property(DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE', False), Xlib.Xatom.ATOM,
                      32, [DISP.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED', False), ],
                      Xlib.X.PropModeReplace)
    DISP.flush()
    w.map()
    EWMH.setActiveWindow(hWnd)
    EWMH.display.flush()
    return '_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL' in EWMH.getWmWindowType(hWnd, str=True)


def _xlibGetAllWindows(parent=None, title: str = "", klass=None):

    parent = parent or ROOT
    allWindows = [parent]

    def findit(hwnd):
        query = hwnd.query_tree()
        for child in query.children:
            allWindows.append(child)
            findit(child)

    findit(parent)
    if not title and not klass:
        return allWindows
    else:
        return [window for window in allWindows if ((title and window.get_wm_name() == title) or
                                                    (klass and window.get_wm_class() == klass))]


hWnd = pywinctl.getActiveWindow()
sendBehind(hWnd._hWnd)
time.sleep(3)
bringBack(hWnd._hWnd)
```

Comment: That's great! Were you waiting for the update all along?

Comment: Yes! It's a great relief! And no, I didn't know this was gonna be solved in this new update, it's been a good surprise. I will upload a new module version to PyPi. I'm just waiting for testing... a lot, because new version will have some other relevant changes (a very klind github user has been working on a typed version). Thank you so much for your support @AnnZen!